# I want to extract only certain values ​from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Now I have a specific array,

I want to extract only certain element values ​​from this array.

The array looks like this,

I want to extract only the values ​​of the second element myid_01, myid_02.

I've tried regex or split, but it's not as good as I thought.

```
["myEvent(event, 'myId_01',3,'333','10000260','');", "myEvent(event, 'myId_02',3,'abcd','10000260','');"]
```

Expected output:

```
[myId_01,myId_02]
```

Comment: A regex is the best solution here.

Comment: And if you show us what have you tried, much better!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the second argument. Then a better way would be `split()` by `','`

**Note:** This approach will not work for first element. For first element and last element consider the below method.

```js
const arr = ["myEvent(event, 'myId_01',3,'333','10000260','');", "myEvent(event, 'myId_02',3,'abcd','10000260','');"]

let res = arr.map(x => x.split(',')[1].trim());
console.log(res)
```

First `match()` the text in `()` and then `split()` it by `,` and then return its second element.

```js
const arr = ["myEvent(event, 'myId_01',3,'333','10000260','');", "myEvent(event, 'myId_02',3,'abcd','10000260','');"]

let res = arr.map(x => x.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(/,\s*/)[1]);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Just `strs.map(a => a.split(/,\s*/)[1]))` would work as well.

Comment: @adiga Yes I thought of that. But if OP will want first or last element that way will not work for first element.

Comment: @adiga I have added both the ways. Can you please tell how my regex `/(\(?<=)?[^(]+(?=\))/` to match text between `()` can be better?

Comment: @권민재 you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey heckmark next to it.

Comment: @MaheerAli I don't know lol. I'm garbage at regex. But looking at OP's string, just splitting at `,\s*` should be sufficient.

Comment: @adiga Yes thats true when he want any element in middle. If he will want first or last element in future. It will not work. Because the first element will be then `myEvent(event`

Comment: @MaheerAli aah, sorry, that's what you meant. What about `\((.*)\)`? https://regex101.com/r/xVqfgb/1

Comment: @adiga Though it will includes `(` or `)` for first and last. But OP can `slice`  that. This will be better than that complex regex .Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to remove the `g` flag from the regex to get the capturing group (at index `1`) instead of the whole match. `x.match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]`. It will return just the `event, 'myId_01',3,'333','10000260',''` part

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x =["myEvent(event, 'myId_01',3,'333','10000260','');", 
        "myEvent(event, 'myId_02',3,'abcd','10000260','');"];
        
var arr=[];
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  arr.push(x[i].split(",")[1]);
  
}
console.log(arr);
```